# Asp.NetCore + Next.js client project

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, next.js

My question is simple, since next.js is fast becoming the default react template for most projects and it can be used for either client only or server side development, has anyone tried using next.js project instead of CRA with asp.net core webapi in the template that VS2019 comes with? I just tried only to be treated with some errors about the cra server not responding in a timely manner listing Timespans in the exception details etc.
So just to be clear, I want to know has anyone tried using asp.net core and next.js in a mono-project setup kinda like they have the create react app (CRA) and asp.net core and IdentityServer setup.

If yes, any links would be awesome or any kinda tips implementing this would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Yes, I tried Next.js with Core 3.1 this fall. But I never managed to make SSR running, hence the Next.js-pages are all static (generated using `next export`). As I remembered it, you'll need an extra Express server to do SSR. 

The project resides in a public GitHub repo, send me a PM if you're interested in the details. BR

Comment: @RoarS. I am definitely interested. I would like to move away from CRA and Asp.Net Core as it comes in the template. its can be slow at times and packages are often 3 versions old.

Comment: Link to repo sent to your hotmail account. Please note that you'll need Cosmos Db Emulator to run the project on localhost. BR.